# What happens if you do not have any cards left in the Infection deck? (Minor spoilers)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

To keep things general and mostly spoiler free, some abilities and events let you destroy cards from the Infection deck. If you do this enough times, there won't be any cards left. What happens in that case?

As the game progresses more, slightly different but similar scenarios could occur.

Package 6 spoiler below:

> Coupled with the inoculation introduced in package 6, you don't even need to destroy them all. Some could be inoculated and in package 6, there they are effectively out of the game until an epidemic is drawn. What happens during the Infect step of a turn when the only Infection cards are in package 6?

Turning point 2 spoiler:

> Infection cards for Forsaken cities are ignored and moved to the game end area when drawn, effectively leading to the same situation. What happens if you have a deck full of Forsaken cities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From page 14 of the [rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/38/ec/38ec25b0-821b-4c2e-b925-27c4a4038acd/pandemic_legacy_season_2_rules.pdf)

> In the rare case you get through the entire Infection deck, reshuffle
>   it and move the Infection Rate marker forward 1 space on the Infection
>   Rate track. If this causes the rate to change during the “Infect”
>   step, use the old rate when determining how many cards to draw.

If there are no cards in the draw pile or the discard deck, you've lost. Like, REALLY lost. Even if you say that the Infection Rate just goes to max and then nothing happens when you have to draw an infection card and there is no deck, you can't win the game without adding cards to the infection deck (by connecting cities to the grid) and as soon as you do, you now draw that card repeatedly and will lose the game very quickly. Not to mention that at some point you had to have only a few cards in the infection deck, and you probably lost very quickly at that point too. Even better, you now lose every subsequent game during the setup phase. So, I'd recommend not doing that.

Comment: I would also add this from page 15 about ending the game as it seems like that would be what happens when the infection deck is empty. " Immediately when the Incident marker reaches the last space of the Incident track"

Comment: Incident track and Infection Rate track are different. Technically I don't think reaching the end of the Infection Rate track ends the game. You can actually reach the end of the Infection Rate track normally, and the rules say it just stays at the end then.

Comment: Knowing what card you're going to draw (if it's the only one in the discard pile, after having connected a new city) could be an advantage though - just put a bunch of cubes on that one city, eschewing all others, and you're set.

Comment: And further, once you've connected a new city, you can proceed to destroy those infection cards just like you destroyed the others, putting you in the same situation of having no deck to draw from.

Comment: I don't see any way in which drawing the same card 5 times per turn is going to be a good thing. There are reasons why your strategy of just dumping supplies on that city wouldn't work, but they involve spoilers. I can include them in the answer if you would like.

Comment: @bwarner Not sure if those reasons should go in this answer, or if I should ask a new question...

Answer (score -4):

I have not played season 2 yet, however whenever I run into these situations in other games I think of what would be *reasonable* thematic-wise. If there is nowhere to spread the virus then it doesn't spread. Or perhaps you revive one of the infected cities because the virus was in fact dormant. Whatever sounds fair, fun and appropriate. It is a cooperative game after all, so you should be able to come up with some realistic outcome with your fellow players.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is speculation on what would be done based on the theme of the game.